# Access 2003 Need to create a user interface where user can select from field list and return distinct values

Tags: ms-access-2003

I'm still working with the same database in which the table name stays the same but the field names will be different for each use. I'd like to create an option on the main form where the user clicks a command button to display a list of fields in the table (named'Scrubbed'), then selects a field from the list, and immediately a window opens up displaying the distinct field values. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot with VBA, including creating a query on the fly. Comboboxes and listboxes have a RowSource option Field List, which will list the fields in your table.

Edit

Here is your code with a few changes:

```
Private Sub Command206_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strScrubbedValue As String

   ''I suspect this is running in the form, so Me
   strScrubbedValue = Me.ComboListScrubbedFields

   ''Where the table is called Scrubbed
   strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT " & strScrubbedValue & " FROM Scrubbed"

   ''No need to execute, it is just a row source
   ''DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

   Me.Combo213.RowSource = strSQL
End Sub
```

I suggest you name your controls with meaningful names.

Comment: Thank you--the combobox was the perfect solution to list the fields in my table. However I'm having trouble with the next step, which is to display a list of distinct values for whichever field the user selects from the combobox. I've created a second combobox with a command button with code below. When I try to run it I get the error message "A RunSql action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement"

Comment: Private Sub Command206_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim strScrubbedValue As String

strScrubbedValue = [Forms]![Form1]![ComboListScrubbedFields]
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT" & [Forms]![Form1]![ComboListScrubbedFields].Value
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
Me.Combo213.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub

Comment: Good. You might like to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) at some stage.

Comment: Hi, I've read the faq. Could you be a little more specific about which rules or best practices I'm not complying with? I appreciate this board as a resource and do not want to offend anyone.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much, it is not written in stone. I am not offended and anyone who is will probably let you know soon enough :)